# Crunch Less Editor won't open files?

Tags: air, editor, adobe

for some reason the Less editor CRUNCH is not opening any files anymore. I don't know why this is happening. I did a reboot, I did an uninstall/reinstall of both AIR and CRUNCH. When I fire Crunch back up to start I instead get the GUI with no functionality and no opening of any files from the menu?

Any ideas how to fix this?

UPDATE here's the fix:
Found the answer on the Facebook page (of all the places) "Zac Evans: ok, so i managed to fix the problem by removing the crunch.app folder under C:\Users###\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\AIR\ELS" The mac fix is to search your main library for the ELS folder and delete the crunch data within that.

Comment: Found the answer on the Facebook page (of all the places) "Zac Evans: ok, so i managed to fix the problem by removing the crunch.app folder under C:\Users\###\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\AIR\ELS" The mac fix is to search your main library for the ELS folder and delete the crunch data within that.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: Found the answer on the Facebook page (of all the places) "Zac Evans: ok, so i managed to fix the problem by removing the crunch.app folder under C:\Users###\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\AIR\ELS"

After both rebooting and re-installing Crunch and Air -The MAC fix is to search your main library for the ELS folder and delete the crunch data within that.

Comment: This fixed it for me.

To make it easier to find on mac (although search is still a viable option) you can go to
(your user folder)->Library->Application Support->Adobe->AIR->ELS